# Is this function re-entrant?

Tags: c, reentrancy

DNM_Manager.c

```
struct DNM_s
{
    uint32_t Addr;
    uint32_t SerialNum;
    uint32_t SubnetMask;
    uint16_t Tick;
    uint8_t Name[NAME_SIZE];
}DNMTemp;

pDNM DNMManager_New(void)    //reentrant?
{
    return &DNMTemp;
}
```

[GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reentrant-function/) says: To be reentrant, the function may not use global and static data.

I do use global data "DNMTemp" in this case. However, DNMTemp's value is not changed and function only return its address.

Comment: This function is reentrant, but whatever you call it from probably isn't.

Comment: I don't understand it. Can you give me an example?

Comment: You are handing out the same pointer for every call, so everyone who calls it will be accessing the same object.  Whatever function calls this one, it will probably use that pointer for something that could be messed up by a reentrant call to the same function.

Comment: What global data do you think it uses? It doesn't use the value of `DNMTemp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

From the tag excerpt of [reentrancy](/questions/tagged/reentrancy):

> A subroutine is considered reentrant if it can be safely called before a previous call has completed.

In your case, since the function only returns the address of a global (static) variable, which should remain constant after the program starts, the function is well re-entrant.

IMO, reentrant function *can* access global and static data, *without changing any*, so obtaining the address of a global variable isn't bad for a reentrant function.

Comment: To your IMO, if global/static data is being changed then what happens?

Comment: @AndyLin Consider this minimal example: `f() { return ++x; }` If it's called concurrently by two threads, the result may possibly be both threads getting `x+2` as the result, when one of them would be expecting `x+1`.

Comment: I meant, although reentrant function doesn't change data, but may reads data that is being changed(and still not complete) by other thread and result in wrong reading.

Comment: @AndyLin If the data is changed by something other than this function itself, it doesn't affect the reentrancy of this very function.

Answer (score 1):

When considering the if the function is reentrant or not the example has to be a bit less trivial than this one.

```
pDNM DNMManager_New(void)    //reentrant?
{
    return &DNMTemp;
}
```

But the reference to the `DNMTemp` (its address) will remain the same during the program execution so this function is reentrant.

But if you access any **real** data it will not.

```
uint32_t DNMManager_read(void)    //reentrant?
{
    return SerialNum;
}
```